# How to select previous or next rows in a query?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I would like to select rows of a column and show it side by side by the same column that is shifted by one either up or down. Something like this:

```
=QUERY(A2:E6,"select A, LEAD(A)")
```

OR

```
=QUERY(A2:E6,"select A, LAG(A)")
```

I tried `OFFSET`, but it offsets both columns, not one of them.

`LEAD` and `LAG` don't exists in [Google's query language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage). Is there any workaround?

Comment: Why do you want to use `QUERY`? Are you open to use other functions?

Answer (score 1):

You could use plain `OFFSET` with array stacking:

```
={A2:E6,OFFSET(A2:E6,1,0)}
```